# Wicket - Set default value to Textfield with CompoundPropertyModel

Tags: forms, null, wicket, textfield, default-value

I have a CompoundPropertyModel which maps to my Object.

e.g.

```
final TextField<String> adresseName = new TextField<String>("Adresse");
```

maps to

```
public class Invoice implements Serializable{

   private String adresse;

   public String getAdresse() {
       return adresse;
   }
   public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
       this.adresse = adresse;
   }
}
```

But if the object adresse is null or not set, I want a default value e.g. "" to be set into the textfield.

How could I do that?

regards, dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setConvertEmptyInputStringToNull(false) should do it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is to make sure `Invoice.getAdresse()` returns an empty string instead of `null`.

```
public String getAdresse() {
   return addresse != null ? adresse : "";
}
```

After all, if `null` isn't a valid value, it's not the UI layer's job to enforce that rule.

**Update:** If you must use Wicket for this, your other option is to make use of model chaining. First you need to create a model that sets the default value on querying.

```
class HackyModel extends Model {

    public Object getObject() {
        Invoice ret = (Invoice)super.getObject();
        if( ret != null && ret.getAddresse() == null ) {
           ret.setAddresse( "" );
        }
        return ret;
    }
 }
```

Then pass this model into the constructor of `CompoundPropertyModel`. When Wicket tries to set/get any field through the `CompoundPropertyModel`, your model will be invoked first to retrieve the backing `Invoice` object, which acts as a sort of filter.

This is not a nice solution as `Model.getObject()` shouldn't modify the backing object but it's probably the cleanest of the possible hacks you have to employ to get around a poorly thought-out POJO.

Comment: the thing is: I am not allowed to manipulate the POJO's :S is there no other way?